# event is not fired on popup button click in asp.net popup

Tags: asp.net, popup

i want to open a popup on buttonclick from a page in asp.net where my popup is ascx and it is embed in popup.aspx.now when i click on the accept button on popup window i want to pass some info to parent page,but i am not getting any way to do this.The events are not fired.

Mypage.aspx which contains the button.onclick mypopup.aspx is called in which i have placed mypop.ascx.It contains two buttons Accept and reject from where i am redireted to mypage.aspx.On accept and deny button click i want to add some data in session based on which i want to perform some logic but the click event is not firing.
Please also give me the reason why i am not getting the event click.
popup.ascx code is

```
<a id="acceptbtn" runat="server" class="blueButton">Accept</a><asp:Button ID="btnHiddenaccept" OnClick="hdnButtonaccept_Click" runat="server" style="display:none;"/>
```

on page load of mypopup.ascx 
acceptbtn.HRef = HttpContext.Current.Request.UrlReferrer.ToString();

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: please see the mypop.ascx code.I have updated my question